# How to test FullCalendar function which was rewritten with mixin

Tags: angularjs, testing, mocking, fullcalendar, mixins

I use  FullCalendar v2.2.7 and I need to test modified method (computeRange), to which I get access via mixin.
Testing should be via Jasmine/Karma.
Tools: AngularJS, TS.

How can I intercept a function computeRange and mock mixin?
Here is code where I rewrite the function:

```
export default class CustomFullCalendarService {
    constructor() {
        'ngInject';
    }

    public rewriteFullCalendarMethods(fullCalendar) {
        let range;

        fullCalendar.views.month.mixin({
            computeRange() {

                // My own code rewriting computeRange() logic

                return range;
            }
        });
    };
};
```

Comment: Let's go back a step. Is there a specific reason why you decided to rewrite an internal fullCalendar function? What problem were you encountering? I just wonder if there is a better way to solve your overall requirement, either by making better use of fullCalendar's API, or perhaps by upgrading (since you are now 3 versions behind the current version - a lot of features have been added and a lot of bugs have been fixed). It's preferably to avoid customising the source code unless it's 100% necessary, as you can always end up with unexpected problems.

Comment: @ADyson unfortunately there is no choise. Due to the strong rules I can't upgrade version. The function is already changed and now I need to test it.

Comment: Ok but maybe there's even a better way to meet the requirement using v2. What is the specific goal you're trying to achieve with your change? I'm not an expert with these testing tools, so I'll leave that to others but I'm very familiar with fullcalendar's API, so I'm just checking there isn't maybe an easier/better way overall to do what you need.